# Slope of Two Points Using Function

Tags: c, function, return-value

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float slopecalc();


float main()
{
int x1;
int x2;
int y1;
int y2;
float slope;


printf("Please enter values for the first X and Y set\t");
scanf_s(" %d %d", &x1, &y1);

printf("Please enter values for the second X and Y set\t");
scanf_s(" %d %d", &x2, &y2);

printf("The values you have entered are \t Point 1 (%d, %d) \t Point 2 (%d, %d)\n", x1, y1, x2, y2);

slope = slopecalc();

printf("The intersection of the two inputed values is\t %f", slope);

return 0;
}


float slopecalc(int x1,int x2,int y1,int y2){

float dx;
float dy;
float slope;

 dx = x2 - x1;  
 dy = y2 - y1;  
 slope = dy / dx;   

return slope;
}
```

Hey, so I am trying to get the slope of two points that are inputed by the user. I cant seem to be able to understand how to properly use a function to do the calculations then call that function to main and print it to the user. Any help would be great!

Comment: What is "the intersection of two points"?

Comment: To begin with, you shouldn't use `float main()`, which is implementation-defined. `int main(void)` is (one of) the standard and is good.

Comment: You will have to pass the values to the function `intersection` as parameters to get the right value.

Comment: how exactly do I pass the values to the function? And sorry, I meant slope not intersection.

Comment: when calling the `scanf_s()` function, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  In this case, there are only two valid (and one optional) ways to declare the main() function.  All formats return 'int', not 'float'

Comment: the prototype for slopecalc() is missing the parameters, it should be: `float slopecalc( int, int, int, int );`    Then the actual call to slopecalc should be: `slope = slopecalc( x1, c2. y1, y2 );'   After all, how is the function: `slopecalc()` expected to know the parameters unless the code passes the parameters to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `slopecalc` calls for arguments, so you must pass some arguments to the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#ifndef _MSC_VER
#define scanf_s scanf
#endif

float slopecalc(int x1,int x2,int y1,int y2);


int main(void)
{
    int x1;
    int x2;
    int y1;
    int y2;
    float slope;


    printf("Please enter values for the first X and Y set\t");
    scanf_s(" %d %d", &x1, &y1);

    printf("Please enter values for the second X and Y set\t");
    scanf_s(" %d %d", &x2, &y2);

    printf("The values you have entered are \t Point 1 (%d, %d) \t Point 2 (%d, %d)\n", x1, y1, x2, y2);

    slope = slopecalc(x1, x2, y1, y2);

    printf("The intersection of the two inputed values is\t %f", slope);

    return 0;
}


float slopecalc(int x1,int x2,int y1,int y2){

    float dx;
    float dy;
    float slope;

    dx = x2 - x1;
    dy = y2 - y1;
    slope = dy / dx;

    return slope;
}
```

Also note that:

- Using function declaration without a list of arguments `float slopecalc()` isn't good because the compiler won't check if you have proper arguments to call the function.
- Using `float main()` isn't good because it is not standard and I didn't get why you use that odd definition of `main` function.

Comment: okay, that makes sense, but what is the purpose of                                                 `#ifndef _MSC_VER`                                                                                 `#define scanf_s scanf`
`#endif` ?

Comment: @bobblehead808: `scanf_s` is a non-standard function specific to Microsoft. MikeCAT is using a preprocessor directive that substitutes the standard `scanf` for `scanf_s` on non-Microsoft compilers.